# How to install japanese kuromoji analysis plugin in ubuntu 16?

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu

I am using elasticsearch. I have the Japanese data. I want to create index on Japanese data. As I have searched how to install Japanese kuromoji analysis plugin in ubuntu 16, there are lot of sites showing the command. But no one has specified from where I need to use that command. Some references I have viewed are:

1.http://pppurple.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/05/28/141143

2.https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji

None of them stating from where I need to enter that command, they just showed the command only. I did lot of google search, but I am not getting the proper guidance/link.

Can anybody please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured by myself. I checked using command sudo service elasticsearch status, this will show where elasticsearch has been located. In my case "/usr/share/elasticsearch" is the place where elasticsearch has been installed. I go to that path and install the japanese kuromoji analysis plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just googled and find out myself. I checked using command

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

it will show where elasticsearch has been installed.
Here in my case

```
"/usr/share/elasticsearch"
```

is the one where elasticsearch has been installed.
Just go to that path and then install the japanese kuromoji analysis plugin.
Hope this will help others who faced exactly the same.